# VLC Remote control Fullscreen dos not work

Tags: java, android, vlc

so latly i am up on a project where I Code a Android Application wich controls some Applications on my PC for example VLC. So i made it this way that my Server connects to the VLC Remote Interface on Localhost:4040.

I got my application so far that it comunicates with VLC and sending orders to it like: next,prev, louder, shuffle. They work just fine. But my fullscreen method does not do anaything.....

little bit of code:

```
 private static PrintWriter out;            //Output Stream-> VLC Input

 out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                  new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);

out.write("pause"); //Will make VLC Play/Pause
```

I Got my Informations about the "orders" for VLC from this sources:

[Source 1](http://getluky.net/2006/04/19/vlcs-awesome-rc-interface/)

[Source 2:Offical VLC Documentation](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Advanced_Use_of_VLC/#RC_and_RTCI)

So the "order" for fullscreen should be a simple "f" or "F" or "Fullscreen" but if i send this VLC does nothing or simply crashes. Does anyone know why VLC behaves likes this? I also read up on this thread where some dudes got the same error under MAC OSX but none of theyr solutions seems to work for me :

[Remote Fulscreen Error](http://forum.hobbyistsoftware.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=580)

so if anyone got some informations i would be very thankfull for it :)

I am Programming on Java 1.7
Windows 7 Machine and VLC 2.1.5

Best Regards & Happy Programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

After opening a post on the VLC board i got answered. What exactly the bug is, wasnt told to me but it is fixed in the newer version v2.2.0. So far its only a preview but it worked for me :)